# add styling to text area with pure css or javascript or jquery alone

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to check if it is possible to add the styling to textbox similar to the ones used by yahoo for the To field in compose page.. replacing the email id with the name inside a wrapper.. i want to know if this can be achieved using css or javscript?? I will attach a snap so that you can see what Im trying to acheive here.. I wil also add a fiddle link of whta Ive tried and failed[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/sztnN/2/

Comment: No. Text in an input (`type="text"` or a `textarea`) cannot be styled (or at least words/phrases can't be separately styled to the other contents). You can, though, have a `div` absolutely positioned above such an element, and copy the contents of the `input`/`textarea` to the `div`, and style the contents, and child-elements, of that `div`.

Comment: No, you can't put a styled bubble in an input. That "input" is a div that looks like an input, with a hidden input inside it.

Comment: @DavidThomas will it look like the same way yahoo msgbox shows cntnt?

Comment: It could do, all it takes is CSS and, possibly, some JavaScript. I can't say I've used Yahoo! for, well, around five years. So, possibly. If it's properly styled.

Comment: do you have anylink on to show how this works?? the way div is used as input

Answer (score 1):

What JavaScript does here is it converts normal `<input>` or `<textarea>` elements to probably `<div>` elements that hold the values. Here is an example and a guide on how you can achieve that in JQuery:

http://www.devthought.com/projects/jquery/textboxlist/